# How can a predefined list can be used for the summation indices in a JuMP @complements() function?

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I'm trying to use the JuMP and complementarity libraries to solve an MPEC program. The problem is that the complementarity restrictions have summations in them and I haven't been able to define the indices of those summations.

```
using JuMP, Ipopt, Complementarity

G = ["g1","g2","g3","g4"]
P = ["p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6"]
T = ["t1","t2"]

m = Model(with_optimizer(Ipopt.Optimizer))
@variable(m, X[g in G] )
@variable(m, Y[g in G] )
@variable(m, W[p in P] )
@variable(m, Z[g in G, p in P, t in T] )
@variable(m, lambda[g in G] )

for g in G
    @complements(m, 0<=  X[g] + Y[g]*sum(W[p]*sum(Z[g,p,t] for t in T) for p in P), lambda[g] >= 0)
end
```

apparently, it can be done in the following way

```
for g in G
    @complements(m, 0<=  X[g] + Y[g]*sum(W[p]*sum(Z[g,p,t] for t in [1:2]) for p in [1:6]), lambda[g] >= 0)
end
```

But I'm trying to do it with lists of strings (as defined in the first code). Also, the limits of the summations need to be changed constantly.

I've done this before using the @mapping() and @complementarity() functions, but it only works with MCP (not MPEC) problems.

Comment: I read your post, but don't actually see a question here. Can you edit the post better summarise exactly what your question is, and what you want from the community?

Comment: @c.fogelklou the problem I'm having is that I want to create the restrictions for an MPEC problem in a way that the limits of the summation can be changed after each iteration. but the function 'complements()' doesn't allow to use of a predefined variable to create the restriction. So my question is how to use the 'complements()' function in a way that the summation indices can be changed easily. I edited the post in an attempt to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the nonlinear expression in `@complements`. The easiest solution is to extract it into a separate expression:

```
using JuMP, Ipopt, Complementarity

G = ["g1", "g2", "g3", "g4"]
P = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6"]
T = ["t1", "t2"]

m = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
@variable(m, X[g in G])
@variable(m, Y[g in G])
@variable(m, W[p in P])
@variable(m, Z[g in G, p in P, t in T])
@variable(m, lambda[g in G])

@NLexpression(
    m, 
    my_expr[g in G], 
    X[g] + Y[g] * sum(W[p] * sum(Z[g, p, t] for t in T) for p in P),
)

for g in G
    @complements(m, 0 <= my_expr[g], lambda[g] >= 0)
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I edited my post with the values that were missing. After running your code I get the error "Cannot multiply a quadratic expression by an aff. expression error(::String) at error.jl:33..."

Comment: I've updated my answers with the solution.